# Can't find proper context for .findNavController()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, illegalargumentexception

So, I'm working on an Android app etc. I have this Main2Activity with a bottomNavView that helps me switch between ProfileFragment and HomeFragment. The thing is I want to use another navView inside my ProfileFragment, I simulated some kind of TabView so I can see two different fragments inside my ProfileFragment.

So, this is my Main2Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_settings, R.id.navigation_new_post,
                R.id.navigation_notifications, R.id.navigation_profile)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }

    public BottomNavigationView getBottomNavigationView(){
        return findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    }

    public Activity getActivity(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is my ProfileFragment, and here's where the problem is. I can't find the context to use in findNavController() and setupWithNavController():

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProfileViewModel notificationsViewModel;
    private boolean isLoading = false;

    public ProfileFragment() {
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        notificationsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);



        BottomNavigationView navView = root.findViewById(R.id.profile_nav_view);
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_my_posts, R.id.nav_applied_to)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.profile_nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(new Main2Activity(), navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

        return root;
    }

}
```

The error I keep getting: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity

Anyone?

UPDATE: This is the stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.heirup, PID: 17523
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:2772)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:363)
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
        at com.example.heirup.ui.profile.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:38)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7081)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17523 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It will help if you post the stacktrace. Also, the error is pretty clear, at stating that: " ID does not reference a View inside this Activity". Are you sure you have a view with this ID inside this activity's layout?

Comment: I posted the tracktrace too. The view with that ID is in ProfileFragment's layout because that's where I use the second navBar. My second navBar should be referencing to ProfileFragment, but findNavController must get an activity as an argument, not a fragment.

Comment: I think there is a misconception there. That nav controller code, should be on the Activity, not the fragment. Is this a single activity app?

Comment: @ThalisVilela The activity already has the code for it's navbar (the bottomNavigationView,   R.id.nav_host_fragment  ), but ProfileFragment has the code for it's own navBar (nav R.id.profile_nav_host_fragment), which is correctly used in ProfileFragments XML

Comment: Instead of Navigation.findNavController(getActivity()... , try Navigation.findNavController(root...,  or even: root.findNavController... PS: root is the view you are returning.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point but unfortunately none of these 2 worked.. .findNavController only works with an activity as an argument

Comment: What about using the fragment's argumentless findNavController()?

Comment: It changed the situation but did not do the job. The error I get now is on the same line: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{d9a277b V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f08008e app:id/home_container2} does not have a NavController set

Answer (score 0):

Use `findNavController(View v)` with parameter `root.findViewById(#your nav_host id)`